# troubleshooting missing entries using log files

Tags: mysql, logs

Something somewhere (most likely the app) is causing rows to disappear.
I'd like to find if there is a query that would point me in the right direction as to what's going on.

It looks like my bin log was not turned on so I've updated my.conf to include the log

```
log_bin                 = ON
general_log_file        = /tmp/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

but this is only going to update it from this point forward.

Is there any other way of being able to go back to see older queries?

Comment: General log is not binlog, they are very different things.

Comment: Ok, which one can I use to find what query at what time deleted my missing rows?

Answer (score 1):

A `DELETE` (and other writes) will be captured by both logs (assuming you don't have `binlog-do/ignore` setting in my.cnf).  It would be more efficient to use the binlog, but it needs mysqlbinlog to read it.  The general_log is plain text, but it gets huge fast, since it is capturing everything (including reads).

I think both logs have the query time and the login name.  (I hope you are not doing everything as `root`.)

Neither can capture anything that happened when they were turned off.  So turn one or both on now, and hope that the naughty query comes along soon.